# Overriding a base class method in a derived class

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a base class A, having a method "say" that calls from constructor of A. All the heritable classes uses the method "say" like it is. But one of the classes need to redefine this method. How is it possible?

For sure, I can denote base method "say" as abstract, but in that way, i have to copy the same method "say" in all the heritable classes.

If i just redefine method without denoting base one as abstract, it is not gonna be called.

```
public abstract class A(){
     public A(){
        say();  //  <- wanna call this method from heritable class, if its redefined. 
     }
     protected void say(){};
}

public class B extends A(){
     public B(){
        super();
     }
     private void say(){};
}
```

## refactoring 1

```
public abstract class A(){
     public A(){
       //  constructor methods             
     }
     protected void say(){};
     protected void executeSay(){
       say();
     }
}

public class B extends A(){
     public B(){
        super();
        executeSay();
     }
     @Override
     protected void say(){};
}
```

Comment: Your code won't compile as you are changing the visibility of the overriden method

Comment: your question is not much clear, can you please explain little more on it?

Comment: Be careful when calling _virtual_ methods in the constructor. The base class is initialized before the derived class, i.e. the fields in the derived class are _not_ _completely_ initialized when the method in the derived class is invoked.

Comment: @nosid comment my code refactoring plz

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all one must be made clear: calling an overridable method from a constructor is a well-known antipattern. It will almost certainly break your code because the subclass method will be invoked *before the subclass constructor is done* and so will observe an uninitialized object. Thus I should better refrain from giving you detailed advice on Java technicalities involved in achieving this antipattern.

The only safe way to acomplish your requirement is to let the construction finish and only afterwards call an `initialize`-kind of method. If you want to ensure `initialize` is always invoked, make the constructors non-public and provide a factory method instead.

Unfortunately, Java requires quite a bit of work on your part to make this work properly.

Comment: +1 Fixes the problem better than question wanted. Also fastest upvoting streak ever ;)

Comment: can u write the method u suggest to use? @Marco Forberg's solution working well.

Comment: If it's working well for you, then use it and come back once your design gets complex enough that you hit the problem I describe.

Comment: I can not fully understand the problem u've said about. Can u write the solution u suggest plz.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik check for my code refactoring. Will it solve the problem?

Comment: I don't see the point of your `executeSay`. The good thing is that you are not calling `say` from the superclass constructor, but if someoene extends `B` then you repeat the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot instantiate a abstract class. That saying you have to link the abstract class reference to the concrete inherited class.
eg. A a = new B();
If that's the case, and B have redefined the say() method, then the say method in B will be called.

```
public class TestPad {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new B();
    }
}
abstract class A {
    public A() {
    say();
    }
    public void say(){
    System.out.println("A");
    };
}

class B extends A {
    public B() {
    super();
    }
    public void say() {
    System.out.println("B");
    }
}
```

The output will be B

Answer (score 3):

```
public class B extends A {
    public B() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void say() {
        // your diffent say code
    };
}
```

I'm not sure if you are allowed to reduce visibility to private.

Comment: No, you are not allowed to reduce visibility of an overridden method in a child class.

Answer (score 0):

Because of polymorphic method invocation, in your case the B.say() will be invoked if you override it.

But as @sanbhat commented, you need to change visibility of `say()` to `protected`.